# Where is "view servlet" context option in version 7

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

In previous versions of Netbeans I remember the "view servlet" context menu option when you right click anywhere in a jsp page.

I try to find it now in version 7.2.1 but is no where. Is there anywhere hidden and I miss it? If not, how can I see the generated servlet code for a jsp?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't find the `view servlet` option. But you can see the generated source code after you build the project inside dir: `$project_folder/build/generated/src/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java`

The above is for the root index.jsp of the project. I suspect if I use a different server then the path is a little bit different, but it should be in `$project_folder/build/generated/src/..(some other stuff).../jsp/index_jsp.java`